# Стягивание данных с нескольких форм в один компонент

Tags: angular

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столкнулся с такой задачей нужно стянуть данные из нескольких форм в один компонент - Заказ по нажатию кнопки - submit. Подскажите как можно сделать, основная проблема это переиспользование компонента person и при этом пользователь не должен сохранять промежуточно компонент Заказчик, получатели и т д, все данные должно отправляться только при нажатии submit

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: классический пример работы с формой когда одна форма потом нажимаем submit и данные отправляются, в моем случае 4+ формы и должны отправляться данные только при нажатии submit  в родительском компоненте

Comment: Создайте родительскую форму и добавляйте в нее вложенные формы. У FormGroup есть методы addControl/SetControl

Comment: Добавьте пример кода, возможно попробовать сделать форму поменьше, не из такого большого количества подформ. Сейчас не понятно, что у вас не получается в вашей "классической форме"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем основная проблема была в переиспользовании компонента person которая решилась

```
 @ViewChildren(PersonComponent) people!: QueryList<PersonComponent>;
```